# How to fix htaccess ssl https redirect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, pyrocms

I have used search and Google but can't seem to find a solution. I am trying to redirect it to HTTPS but am having some issues. I keep getting:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Below is my htaccess file. I would prefer that instead of adding a code to each html code. I have tried everything and just cant figure it out.

```
# Multiple Environment config
# Set this to development, staging or production
# SetEnv PYRO_ENV production
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Make sure directory listing is disabled
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    # disable the Apache MultiViews directive if it is enabled on the server. It plays havoc with URL rewriting
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Edit: Problem solved Below code Worked. Please Lock

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain(dot)com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: could you please share URL?

Comment: http://gateway-webhosting.ca here you go :p

Answer (score 0):

try below code, it should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RedirectMatch 403 ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$

    # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for reply I tried this code you gave me but am still getting exact same error

Comment: @user3732612 what you can do is try placing just http to https related redirection and remove all other part. And gradually keep on adding other rules. This way you can find line with problem.

Comment: well if I use Rewritecond alone it works but then my pyrocms errors without the rest.

Comment: I checked the code and if I remove everything but https redirect I get same error but if I keep everything and remove the redirect my site loads without SSL redirectt

Comment: do you have any other thing which forces you site to `http`? It looks like because your site working fine with http. but https it has redirection loop.

Comment: I dont see anything ive looked at my files is there a pyrocms plugin to force ssl I didnt see any on the web

Comment: I noticed if I manually type HTTPS it works and My identity is there without redirect code